# How can I map a PostgreSQL varchar[] (array column) to a List<String> in Java using Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a column in PostgreSQL 9.6 of type "character varying[]" which is essentially an array of strings. I am using Dropwizard with Hibernate to handle the database connection. Normally I just need to provide an annotation to define the data type, however, Hibernate is complaining about the deserialization of a varchar[] type. How do I map this to a List in Java?

I have tried implement my own UserType extended class to handle the (de)serialization with no luck. Any help would be most appreciated.

## UPDATE:

I took a look at this [link](https://madhavivaram.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/) posted by @Waqas and I was able to at least create a type that extends UserType to implement the mapping of varchar[] to String[] in Java.

Some differences in my implementation:

- In the `nullSafeSet()` and `nullSafeGet()` methods that need to be implemented (@Override), I had to use a (newer?) class called `SharedSessionContractImplementor` from `org.hibernate.engine.spi` instead of the (older?) class `SessionImplementor`.
- When I implemented this change and added the @Type annotation to my column mapping (in my entity data class) my runtime was complaining about an @Override that apparently wasn't valid for a certain `HibernateBundle` class (error below). Even though maven built the jar without any issues and I only have Java 1.8 installed on my machine (OpenSuse). P.S. I am using Dropwizard 1.2 and I took the declaration of the `HibernateBundle` straight from their documentation. Nevertheless, I deleted the @Override annotation and it works now. Not sure why, or how, but it does.

Error as promised:

```
INFO  [2017-11-08 22:39:06,220] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @1137ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
INFO  [2017-11-08 22:39:06,310] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2017-11-08 22:39:06,312] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method getDataSourceFactory(ApplicationConfiguration) of type new HibernateBundle<ApplicationConfiguration>(){} must override a superclass method
at com.tksoft.food.Application$1.getDataSourceFactory(Application.java:24)
at com.tksoft.food.Application$1.getDataSourceFactory(Application.java:1)
at io.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle.run(HibernateBundle.java:61)
at io.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle.run(HibernateBundle.java:15)
at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:200)
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:42)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
at com.tksoft.food.Application.main(Application.java:30)
```

Any way, this has left me super confused, but it is working so I am happy :) (for now). I just have to figure out if I can map it to a List instead of an array :/

Comment: please share the code you've tried so far

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://madhavivaram.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/mapping-array-column-of-postgres-in-hibernate/

Comment: @Waqas I used that link and had to alter some of the implementation, but I got it to work. I will edit my question to include the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also if you want to check it out I did some work with this 3 years ago although the project was moved to MySQL so work never continued. https://github.com/Namphibian/pgDilato

Comment: This driver is also pretty good with the arrays etc if I remember correctly. https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng

Comment: Thanks @Namphibian, I will check out those projects